# Styling Vectorgrid Layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, styling, vector-tiles

I'm trying to style a map layer for a leafletJS map and have the following code but it doesn't seem to colour at all:

```
var vectorTileOptions = {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                            weight: 2,
                            color: 'yellow',
                            },
};

var mapLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf("/tiles/admin_countries/{z}/{x}/{y}", vectorTileOptions)
```

It's just comes renders the standard blue, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be [found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256888/styling-geoserver-pbf-vector-tiles-in-leaflet), by having a click log `e.layer` to console you can get the property which is used as the key for the `vectorTileOptions` and then style as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
.setStyle({fillColor: '#dd0000', color: '#dd0000', weight: 1, opacity: 0.8, fillOpacity: 0.8});
```

actually, no I think you need to just adjust what you have there:

```
vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                        weight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#9bc2c4'
                        },
```

there is a lot about it here: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#styling-vectorgrids

Comment: Hi Jeremy I get `Uncaught TypeError: L.vectorGrid.protobuf(...).setStyle is not a function` when i have ` var mapillaryLayer` `L.vectorGrid.protobuf("/tiles/admin_countries/{z}/{x}/{y}").setStyle({fillColor: '#dd0000', color: '#dd0000', weight: 1, opacity: 0.8, fillOpacity: 0.8})`
` . Any suggestions? Cheers for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the vectorGrid stuff was an add-on. I adjusted my answer. Does that maybe help?

Comment: Fraid that does nothing, it’s very similar to the approach I started with that I thought would work too, there must be something we are missing but I’m not sure what! The link u added seems to style based on an argument, but I’m not sure what argument I could pass!